# What does the word cap mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In this article:
https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/australians-stuck-abroad-covid/index.html
the word **CAP** is present, what does it mean?

Example:

> Sunday marked two months since Prime Minister Scott Morrison
> introduced cap of just 4,000 international arrivals per week.

So what did the sentence say?

> The citizen of Australia came back is by amount of 4,000 people

or:

> The possible amount of people that their are citizen of Australia is
> 4,000 can be allow to came, so the overhead of people is 4,000.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is the source for those quotes? None of them are proper English, and cap is used here to mean limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Sunday marked two months since Prime Minister Scott Morrison introduced **cap** of just 4,000 international arrivals per week.

In this sentence Cap means that the maximum international arrivals per week in Australia are 4,000.

But **CAP** can mean a lot of things and it can also take on connotations related to slang or urban speaking.

Cambridge: [Cambridge dictionary for CAP](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/cap)